# How to bulk import many Word documents into SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, import, openrowset

I need to import ~50,000 Word documents (`.doc` and `.docx`) from a single directory into a SQL Server 2016 database table so that I can use full text indexing and then search the documents' contents.

Since this is a one-off task and the database won't be required for long I'm not concerned with performance or the arguments for using `FILESTREAM` or FileTables.

I've just created a database with a single table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyDocument]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentName] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Extension] NCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentContent] VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyDocument] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

Now I'm looking for a way to get my documents into the table. There are plenty of examples online for importing a single document into a SQL Server database table using `OPENROWSET`, but they require me to specify a name for the file, which is obviously no use for my requirements.

I can't believe there isn't a well-documented and straightforward way to do this but a couple of hours of searching haven't turned anything up, which is starting to make me doubt this is even possible, but surely it is?

Can anybody give me an example snippet of T-SQL for importing multiple files into the database? Or suggest how else it might be achieved?

Comment: Here's a bit of powershell to insert (update) into a database. You just have to extend it to loop through your existing files I guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974182/inserting-image-into-sql-server-column-of-type-varbinarymax-using-powershell

Comment: .. and another. Again needs to be altered to loop through your source files. https://philergia.com/2011/03/18/inserting-binary-objects-into-a-sql-server-table-using-a-stored-procedure-and-powershell-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a PowerShell script to import all ".docx" files in the specified folder using a parameterized query along with a `FileStream` parameter value to stream file contents to the database rather than loading the entire file contents into client memory.

```
# import all documents in specified directory using file stream parameter
try {

    $timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    $insertQuery = @"
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyDocument (DocumentName, Extension, DocumentContent)
        VALUES(@DocumentName, @Extension, @DocumentContent);
"@
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI")
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($insertQuery, $connection)
    $documentNameParameter = $command.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 255)
    $documentExtensionParameter = $command.Parameters.Add("@Extension", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 10)
    $documentContentParameter = $command.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarBinary, -1)
    $connection.Open()

    $filesToImport = Get-ChildItem "E:\DocumentsToImport\*.docx"
    $importedFileCount = 0
    foreach($fileToImport in $filesToImport) {
        $documentContentStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($fileToImport.FullName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
        $documentNameParameter.Value = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fileToImport.FullName)
        $documentExtensionParameter.Value = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($fileToImport.Name)
        $documentContentParameter.Value = $documentContentStream
        [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $documentContentStream.Close()
        $importedFileCount += 1
    }
    $connection.Close()

    $timer.Stop()

    Write-Host "$importedFileCount files imported. Duration $($timer.Elapsed)."
}
catch {
    throw
}
```